# Linear Algebra: question on Wiki definition of transformation matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, linear-transformations

I'm reading a [Wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transformation_matrix#Finding_the_matrix_of_a_transformation) section which has the following equality:

$$
A(\mathbf v) = A(\sum v_i \mathbf e_i) = \sum v_i A(\mathbf e_i)
$$

what property or theorem allows the summation to be moved outside of the transformation argument?

I think [homogeneity](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Homogeneous_function) may apply to this:
$$
f(c\mathbf u) = c f(\mathbf u), f(\mathbf u + \mathbf v) = f(\mathbf u) + f(\mathbf v)
$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since $A$ is a matrix, the salient property is [left-distributivity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Distributive_property) of matrix multiplication over addition. Given an $l \times m$ matrix $A$ and two $m \times n$ matrices $B$ and $C$, then the following holds:
$$A(B + C) = AB + AC.$$
This includes the case where $B$ and $C$ are column vectors (i.e. $n = 1$). This can be extended by induction to finite sums:
$$A\left(\sum_i B_i\right) = \sum_i AB_i.$$

Comment: It appears this property can be applied.  Is the commutative property applied as follows?  $
A(\mathbf v) = A(\sum v_i \mathbf e_i) = A(\sum \mathbf e_i  v_i) =  \sum A \mathbf e_i  v_i = \sum v_i A(\mathbf e_i)
$

Comment: Also does the homeomorphic or operation preserving properties of a linear map also apply?  https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_map

Comment: @Nick The $v_i$s in the wiki are scalars and the $\mathbf{e}_i$ are vectors, so it doesn't really make sense to write $\mathbf{e}_i v_i$. There is another property of matrix multiplication (which I don't know the name of) where $(\lambda A)B = A(\lambda B) = \lambda(AB)$, where $\lambda$ is a scalar, and $A, B$ are appropriately-sized matrices. It's similar to scalar homogeneity (part of the definition of linearity) of vector space maps.

Comment: Product with a scalar property: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_multiplication#Product_with_a_scalar - So here $\mathbf A v_i \mathbf e_i = (\mathbf A \mathbf B) c = c (\mathbf A \mathbf B) =  v_i \mathbf A \mathbf e_i$

Comment: @Nick Well, you have me there! It does make sense; I don't usually work with modules and non-commutative rings, so I forgot about that.

Comment: Actually, Wiki says product with a scalar $c \mathbf A = \mathbf A c$ is the commutative property.  Therefore, I believe my first comment here holds (although I could have shown the steps of swapping $v_i$ to the left using the comm prop.)